# Xcode не компилирует любой Assembler код

Tags: c, xcode, ассемблер

Создаю проект в Xcode и выбираю язык как C. Создаю assembly file в проекте и закидываю туда код представленный ниже. Получаю при компиляции следующий отчет: https://pastebin.com/2ya6NaKt
Вопрос. Что оно хочет от меня?

```
"title word  ;z=(x-y)*((x+y)/2)
dat1 segment
x db 8
y db 6
c db 2
z dw ?
dat1 endS

stk1 segment
db 256 dup(?) 
stk1 ends

cod1 segment
assume cs:cod1,ds:dat1,ss:stk1
start:
mov ax,dat1
mov ds,ax

mov al,x
sub al,y    ;x-y
mov bl,al   ;x-y

mov al,x
add al,y    ;x+y
cbw

idiv c      ;(x+y)/2

imul bl     ;(x-y)*((x+y)/2)

mov byte ptr [z],al
mov byte ptr [z+2],ah


mov ah,4Ch
int 21h
cod1 endS
end start
```

Comment: Раз ругается на title, я бы попробовал убрать эту строку

Comment: Логично, но он еще ругается на кучу других переменных.

Comment: Возможно ваш компилятор вообще не знает как скомпилировать данный пример (данный пример для masm или tasm под DOS, а компилируете вы под macos (или как она сейчас называется), насколько я понимаю, и я без понятия что у вас за компилятор).

Comment: Почти гарантированно заработает, если будете компилировать с помощью tasm под dosbox, и там же запускать.

Comment: Наверное (как и большинство \*nix) хочет [AT&T](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/AT%26T-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81) ассемблерный код